# Primeng's Virtual Scroll does not display values ​on the screen

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, infinite-scroll

I'm using primeng's virtual scroll so that at each scroll he makes a request, but I noticed that he's not listing the values ​​for me

my html is this way

```
<p-virtualScroller [value]="virtualCars" scrollHeight="450px" [itemSize]="100" [rows]="100" 
        [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadCarsLazy($event)">

    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item" let-i="index">
        <div class="car-details">
            <div>
              <img alt="data.titulo" [src]="imagemDocumento(data.arquivo.tipoMime.mime)">
              <div>
                    <b>{{anexos.usuarioLog.nome}}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p-splitButton id="menu" icon="pi pi-list" appendTo="body" [model]="items" (onDropdownClick)="onDropdownClick(data)"></p-splitButton>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="loadingItem">
        <div class="car-details">
            <div>
                <div class="car-item-image empty-car-item-image"></div>
                <div>
                    <b class="empty-car-item-text"></b>
                    <div class="empty-car-item-text"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="empty-car-item-button"></div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-virtualScroller>
```

my ts is this way

```
anexos: Anexo[];
  virtual: Anexo[];
  sortKey: string;

  constructor(
    private anexosService: AnexosService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.anexos = Array.from({ length: 10000 }).map(() => this.anexosService);
    this.virtual = Array.from({ length: 10000 });
  }

  loadCarsLazy(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let loadedCars = this.anexos.slice(event.first, (event.first + event.rows));

      Array.prototype.splice.apply(this.virtual, [...[event.first, event.rows], ...loadedCars]);

      //trigger change detection
      this.virtual = [...this.virtual];
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I do not understand the reason for not listing, he is making the request! just not listing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have `OnPush` enabled on the enclosing component? I noticed this table won't load properly if `OnPush` is enabled at the same time virtual scrolling is.